# Setting the entryDate when adding a note doesn't seem to work

Tags: attask

I'm importing data from a legacy system into Workfront. I would like to bring over all the comments and have them retain the original date the comment was made. I've tried including the entryDate field in my post, but Workfront seems to ignore the value. Is there a way to add a note in Workfront with a prior date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative, Chris: entryDate is a generated timestamp ("get, but not set") -- think Oracle Trigger In Insert.

A common convention is to prefix the original dates onto the comments you are loading.

Regards,
Doug

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. I like your suggestion to include the original date in the note. Thanks!